# Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 C++ Input/Output Error

Tags: c++, netbeans

I installed netbeans C++ on windows 7 and used Cywgin4 as the compiler. When I run any program even a simple Hello world it does compile and run however I also get the error below. I can't seem to find any reference to it online. Can anyone point me in the right direction for a solution? Thanks!

> read from master failed
>                          : Input/output error
>
> RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 47ms)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I do not understand all the surrounding details of this problem as I am new to C/C++. However, if you:

- Open up NetBeans
- Right click on your C++ project file
- Select "Properties"
- There should be a category called "Run".

Under this category, find the option called `Console Type` and make sure that `Standard Output` is selected as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: NetBeans IDE Screenshot]

I was having the same problems when the console type was selected as `Internal Terminal`.

For my setup, changing this option to `Standard Output` got rid of this error. However, I do not fully understand how this change affects the overall properties of my project. Wish you good luck.

Comment: This solved the problem on my side. But it would be great to understand what is the difference between these types of outputs.