# Get Qt up and running with Netbeans

Tags: c++, windows, qt, netbeans

I'm trying to get started writing a Qt program in Netbeans, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.
I'm trying to follow [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/cnd/qt-applications.html?print=yes) tutorial from the Netbeans site which explains how to do just that, however it seems to be outdated.

> 1. Install NetBeans IDE and the C/C++ plugin module, as explained in Configuring the NetBeans IDE for C/C++/Fortran. Do not install
>      compilers yet.
> 2. Exit NetBeans IDE.
> 3. Download the MinGW installer from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw.
> 4. Run the MinGW installer, which should have a file name similar to mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe.

Steps 1-4 are easy. Although the name of the installation-file for MinGW is "mingw-get-setup.exe"

> 5. In the MinGW installer, select the following components to install:
>
>    - C
>    - C++
>    - MSYS Basic System
>    - MinGW Developer Toolkit

There's no options with these exact names.

- For **C** I picked the bin-version of "mingw32-gcc"(The GNU C Compiler)
- For **C++** I picked the bin-version of "mingf32-gcc-g++"(The GN C++ Compiler)
- For **MSYS Basic System** I picked the bin-version of "msys-base"(A Basic MSYS Installation (meta))
- Lastly for **MinGW Developer Toolkit** I picked "mingw-developer-toolkit"(An MSYS Installation for MinGW Developers (meta))

> 6. Download and install the following Qt software from http://qt-project.org/downloads. 
>      Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows (minGW 4.4 317 MB)
>      Qt Creator 2.8.1 for Windows (51 MB)

After signing up and reaching the download-page I find a download for Qt Creator, but not one for Qt Libraries.
I figured I might need to download Qt Online Installer which I did.
During the component selection I select to install **Qt5.5->MinGW 4.9.2 32 bit** and **Tools->MinGW 4.8.2** but still can't find any Qt Libraries.

At this stage I can compile and run Qt Applications in Qt Creator fine.
I create a Qt application in Netbeans and try compiling it with the following Tool collection: [image]

I get

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)

but I then get:

> read from master failed
>                          : Input/output error
>
> RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 310ms)

I also tried with the same toolset but with MinGW from "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32\bin" hoping that the compiler from the same installer as Qt would work, but it gives me the same error.

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916451/netbeans-ide-8-0-2-c-input-output-error

Comment: Thank you. I did find that prior to posting this. I tried it and it gave me a different error then instead. Don't really remember what it was but I solved it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that if I run it in debug mode I got an error code of 0xc0000139 rather than a generic "Run Failed". It lead me to the following thread: http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-53617.html
And I followed suggestion in this post:

> It seems to me you are building and running the project with two different compiler runtimes. I would suggest a drastic approach -- uninstall every Qt and MinGW instance you have and (re)install only one Qt with MinGW set.

At first I tried reconfiguring things to solve the possible problem of having multiple compiler runtimes but nothing I did seemed to help.
So I did as suggested and uninstalled everything, removed PATHs and NB toolsets, projects and everything.

Then I started with the Qt online installer and installed **Qt>Qt 5.5>MinGW 4.9.2 32 bit** and **Qt>Tools>MinGW 4.9.2**.
This left me without Msys so I run mingw-get-setup.exe and installed nohing but **MSYS Basic System**. I assured everything was in my Environment variable PATH (C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin;C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;).

I set up this toolset in NB:
[image: NB Tool Set]

Then created a new Qt project in NB and tried compiling+running it but it gave me an error which I don't recall now. I restarted NB and it gave me a different error this time which I don't recall either.
I rebooted my system and tried once more and finally it was working.